# SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default - Error when importing Eventbus in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, syntax, vuejs3, event-bus

I have written two VueJS files, which mandatorily need to be connected using the Event-Bus pattern.
Upon importing the EventBus into my App.vue file, I get greeted with the mentioned error: `SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default`.

**This is my code:**

```
// ./eventbus.js
import Vue from 'vue';
export const { EventBus } = new Vue();

// ./App.vue
...
import { EventBus } from './eventbus.js';
...

// ./Competitor.vue
...
import { EventBus } from './eventbus.js';
...
```

What do I have to change for my EventBus-import to work?

To no avail, I have already attempted advice from somewhat similar posts, like putting curly brackets around my "EventBus"-object.

Comment: what are you trying to do here? -- export const { EventBus } = new Vue(); -- is this where the error is being raised?

Comment: @ThisGuy I am attempting to import my EventBus into another file (for example App.vue). The error is only raised, when App.vue includes the statement "import { EventBus } from './eventbus.js';" If I debug the localhost website in Chrome, I get a slightly more detailed error message, which reads: "Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=9a9d5790' does not provide an export named 'default' (at eventbus.js?t=1697037455681:1:8)"

Comment: k. I would suggest trying without that line, seems like you are trying to import EventBus from a new Vue(), which does not have that as an export... then you are trying to export it again.  See what happens, or doesn't :D

Comment: I'm wondering if your `export const { EventBus } = new Vue();` line should instead just be `export const EventBus = new Vue();` but then leave the others as is.

Comment: @ThisGuy If I remove the import statement, I would create the EventBus and never use it - that'd be pretty pointless. Am I possibly misunderstanding your response?

Comment: @MattP Tried that - Results in same error and no difference

Comment: Hey Matt, listen, I don't know your experience, or what you are really trying to do. My experience has been that it is easier to comment something out, rather than create something new. The idea of removing something is to see if your error changes. You wrote the code that doesn't work, I have no responsibility for your application. I'm only trying to help and it's your choice to listen to me. We are trying to find the problem, not finalise your application. So, comment away. Your error says that vue.js does not declare a default export, so maybe wrap Vue in curly brackets?

Comment: @ThisGuy Your advice changed the error message. It is now "SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: Vue". Any suggestions on how I could get to the bottom of this issue?

Comment: @MattP my bad, Man, I thought the OP was you, sorry about that. FailX, I would recommend that you stabilize your Vue app first then tackle this "EventBus" stuff. Like, remove any imports of EventBus. It looks like your problem is in this file: // ./eventbus.js
import Vue from 'vue';
export const { EventBus } = new Vue(); I suggest that you remove / comment stuff out until you get a Vue object that is working, then add your eventbus and expand.  Something like this might simply be a missed character, sorry I can't do more. https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html